# check status connected nordvpn bash script

Tags: bash, variables, compare

I am trying to check if my computer is connected with VPN (NORDVPN)

My script in bash is the following:

```
STATUS = "$(nordvpn status | head -n 1)"
printf "STATUS %s\n" "$STATUS"

if [[ $STATUS == "Status: Disconnected" ]]
then
        echo "Disconnected from VPN..."
        nordvpn connect Salt_Lake_City
fi
```

I get the following output:

```
STATUS: command not found
STATUS
```

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: What is the raw output of `nordvpn status` ? There's no spaces around `=` in shell

Comment: Learn to fix any  issues flagged by https://shellcheck.net . Include a proper first line, usually `#!/bin/bash`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do:

```
status="$(nordvpn status | head -n 1)"
printf "STATUS %s\n" "$status"

if [[ $status == "Status: Disconnected" ]]
then
    echo "Disconnected from VPN..."
    nordvpn connect Salt_Lake_City
fi
```

or

```
status="$(nordvpn status)"
printf "STATUS %s\n" "$status"

if [[ $status == "Status: Disconnected"* ]]
then
    echo "Disconnected from VPN..."
    nordvpn connect Salt_Lake_City
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

At the end, I have done some simply changes.

I have used the keyword SET, I have used backticks.....

```
set status = `nordvpn status | head -n 1`
printf "STATUS %s" "$status"

if [[ $status == "Status: Disconnected" ]]
then
        echo "Disconnected from VPN..."
        nordvpn connect Salt_Lake_City
else
        echo "Connected..."
fi
```

**Thanks to everybody **

Comment: This is a syntax error. Are you sure you use bash?